# Go across the street Vs Cross the street

Tags: sentence-construction

If you need to get into the pharmacy...

> ...go across the street, you will get into the pharmacy located there.

vs:

> ...cross the street, you will get into the pharmacy located there.

Comment: In normal use you would not say "get into" in the context of going to another location, though it is likely you will go into the building after you get there. Instead of "into" use "to". ex. "If you need to ***get to*** the pharmacy, go across the street; you will ***get to*** the pharmacy located there". Also the first ***get to*** would be more natural as ***go to*** and the second one ***arrive at***.

Comment: Agree with @user3169 that "get into" sounds awkward.  I wouldn't make a distinction between "cross the street" and "go across the street."  However, I _try_ to be succinct, so I'd go with "cross the street."

Answer (score 4):

Cross the street focuses more on the part about walking across the street, things like watching out for incoming traffic.

Go across the street focuses more on the fact that you must cross the street to get to there, but that the process of walking on the street isn't as important. The part about watching out for cars is implied.

Answer (score 2):

You can use say "cross the street" or "go across the street" to get to the pharmacy, without a difference in meaning.

The only difference is that the word "cross" had been used as a transitive verb in the first sentence and the word across has been used as a preposition in the second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Cross the street - the act of walking to the other side
Across the street - the destination or location

I must cross the street to meet Mark.
I met Mark at Tim Horton's which was across the street from his house.